# DocumentDB throwing exception: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I am trying to access a record from my document db cluster and when I try to access the record, it throws the following error:

```
org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command: Execution of command with request id 48 failed to complete successfully in 149.61 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:28}] to server localhost:9200
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.InstanceCreatorImpl.getInstance(InstanceCreatorImpl.java:90)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decode(PojoCodecImpl.java:122)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decode(PojoCodecImpl.java:125)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.decode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultArrayCodec.decode(CommandResultArrayCodec.java:52)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:60)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
    at org.bson.internal.LazyCodec.decode(LazyCodec.java:48)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
```

I have configured the mongo client in the following way:

```
CodecRegisty codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                      fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                                                     .automatic(true)
                                                     .build()));


final MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                                                        .credential(credential)
                                                        .retryWrites(false)
                                                        .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder
                                                                .enabled(docDbSecret.isSsl())
                                                                .invalidHostNameAllowed(isInvalidHostNameAllowed))
                                                        .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> builder
                                                                .hosts(Collections.singletonList(serverAddress)))
                                                        .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                                                        .build();

MongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

Sample DocumentPojo:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public final Class Document {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public Document(@BsonProperty String a, @BsonProperty String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    @BsonId
    public String getId() {
       return a+":"+b;
    }
 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

When I try to access from the mongoshell - I am able to query the document using `find()` command.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that we need to provide variableName to `@BsonProperty` and also add ANNOTATION_CONVENTION to CodecRegistry.